# How to get react props inside a map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a react function with props `active`.

```
// About Page
export default function About() {
  return <Menu active="about" />;
}

// Menu Component
function Menu(props) {
  const items = ["home", "about", "services", "contact"];

  return (
    <nav>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(props);
        return <li className={`${props.active === item && "active"}`}> {item} </li>;
      })}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

How do I get the `props.active` inside the map() function? it's returning `undefined` right now.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me and `props` should be available where you're accessing it. Is it because you have `class=` instead of `className=`?

Comment: Did you console and see if its really props.active thats undefined. Because rest looks fine as @ClaireLin pointed out.

Comment: I did console.log it returned `{}` the class instead of className is a typo error in the question. fixed it.

Comment: Where and how are you using it in App.js or index.js ? Can you please addd that block of code.

Comment: What's the `props` value outside the `map()` ? Is it still undefined ?

Comment: Just checked again and seems props is {} outside as well.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code to a sandbox and it is working. Something should be wrong in your project. Can you add it a code sandbox and share the link so others can see what's going on.

Comment: Here is a demo exactly from your code. As you see it works fine (https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-fog-2q8pv?file=/src/A.js)

Comment: Do you have any HOCs wrapping Menu prior to its use in About? Give a [mre].

Comment: yes, I tried to share codesandbox and its working there. So I guess something is missing in my project. let me see if I can create a minimal reproduction.

Comment: Damn! I was modifying the wrong file while passing props. 3 hours I was confused lol.. Thanks a lot everyone for the help. I'm not sure I should delete this question or not?

Comment: This might help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281849/when-is-it-ok-to-delete-your-own-question

Answer (score 0):

Converted to snippet, Seems props is getting correctly.
(not related, but minor fix, if you use `&&` in class name generation, for the falsy condition classname will be "false")

```js
function About() {
  return <Menu active="about" />;
}

function Menu(props) {
  const items = ["home", "about", "services", "contact"];

  return (
    <nav>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (
          <li className={`${props.active === item ? "active" : "inactive"}`}> {item} </li>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<About />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}

.inactive {
  color: grey
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above sample code in question works flawlessly.

In my project, I was actually modifying the wrong page to provide props, thus got {}

So, I'm writing this answer so that other people won't spend time on it.